# Setting font in framework from XCode project

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, frameworks

My scenario -

I have 3 frameworks - Framework A , Framework B & Framework C.

All uses a common Font - RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf

I want to set this font from XCode project itself, so that if I need to change the font, I will update it in project.

Thanks in advance...!!!